# VS2010 Dissembly window goes on forever?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++

When I am looking at the assembler code in VS2010, in the Dissembler window- if I scroll downwards why does the assembler continue? Is this because it is representing the assembler of  my mouse scrolling? Surely this cannot be because otherwise there would be no way to scroll through the program's assembler if it kept adding more lines??